# 404 bad request error for connecting to socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, http-status-code-400

I want to connect to one socket which needs login before the connection and login parameters are sent as query parameters.

For connecting with socket I am using this library - https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-use-websockets-on-android-with-okhttp-ba5f00aea988

This is working for their demo socket, but I am not able to connect to my socket.

The web code in JavaScript looks like

```
socket : io.connect('52.11.67.123:6060', { query: {user:JSON.stringify({user:usercus}) ,login:JSON.stringify({username:'esw',password:'escrust'})}}),
```

some library is used to connect with the socket and send query parameters.

In android to send query parameters I tried to use Uri.Builder, I matched the url with the clients url which works but still I am not able to connect with it.

Code:

```
 private void start() {

    try {

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("ws")
                .encodedAuthority("52.11.67.123:6060")
                .appendEncodedPath("socket.io/")
                .appendQueryParameter("user", "{\"user\":{\"customer_id\":\"10\",\"customer_group_id\":\"0\",\"password\":\"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055\",\"first_name\":\"iykeone\",\"last_name\":\"Idukpaye\",\"email\":\"iykeidukpaye@gmail.com\",\"address\":\"30\",\"is_company\":\"1\",\"photo\":\"upload/1504896445753.png\",\"business_type\":\"test\",\"ip\":\"\",\"customer_unique_id\":\"271113lq034225\",\"status\":\"0\",\"date_added\":\"2013-11-27 03:42:25\",\"date_login\":\"2016-10-04 09:22:47\",\"online_status\":\"0\",\"is_forget_password\":\"0\",\"customer_add\":\"\",\"phonecode\":\"0\",\"phonecode1\":\"0\",\"phonecode2\":\"0\",\"customer_phone\":\"0\",\"business_info\":\"\",\"bank_ac\":\"012102102\",\"bank_name\":\"bfbdbfsb\",\"routing_no\":\"7895464\",\"bank_address\":\"iykeidukpaye@yahoo.com\",\"bank_country\":\"8\",\"bank_ac_type\":\"current\",\"bank_ac_name\":\"IykeIdukpaye\",\"bank_ac_address1\":\"Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Teest Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test\",\"bank_ac_address2\":\"Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test\",\"dr_cr_card\":\"Mc\",\"purpose_code\":\"CONSULTING\",\"confirmation_code\":\"\",\"dispatcher\":\"1\",\"dispatch_plan\":\"5\",\"dispatcher_id\":\"TDP10LDI\",\"dispatcher_location\":\"[\\\"Local\\\",\\\"Domestic\\\",\\\"International\\\"]\",\"merchant\":\"5\",\"verify\":\"0\",\"customer_phone1\":\"0\",\"customer_phone2\":\"0\",\"verify1\":\"0\",\"verify2\":\"0\",\"dispatch_status\":\"0\",\"dispatch_limit\":\"34800\",\"Ratings\":\"0\",\"deviceNotificationToken\":null,\"bankname\":\"ANTARCTICA\"}}")
                .appendQueryParameter("login", "{\"username\":\"escw\",\"password\":\"escst\"}");

        String myUrl = builder.build().toString()+"&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=voy5xrGfTWNs6nSFAAAr";
    //    String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
        Log.e("socket:",myUrl);

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(myUrl).build();
        EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
        WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);

        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();

    }
    catch (JSONException je)
    {

    }
}
private void output(final String txt) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("response",txt);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, txt,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Clients url Looks like this:

```
 ws://52.11.67.123:6060/socket.io/?user=%7B%22user%22%3A%7B%22customer_id%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22customer_group_id%22%3A%220%22%2C%22password%22%3A%2281dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055%22%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22iykeone%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22Idukpaye%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22iykeidukpaye%40gmail.com%22%2C%22address%22%3A%2230%22%2C%22is_company%22%3A%221%22%2C%22photo%22%3A%22upload%2F1504896445753.png%22%2C%22business_type%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22ip%22%3A%22%22%2C%22customer_unique_id%22%3A%22271113lq034225%22%2C%22status%22%3A%220%22%2C%22date_added%22%3A%222013-11-27%2003%3A42%3A25%22%2C%22date_login%22%3A%222016-10-04%2009%3A22%3A47%22%2C%22online_status%22%3A%220%22%2C%22is_forget_password%22%3A%220%22%2C%22customer_add%22%3A%22%22%2C%22phonecode%22%3A%220%22%2C%22phonecode1%22%3A%220%22%2C%22phonecode2%22%3A%220%22%2C%22customer_phone%22%3A%220%22%2C%22business_info%22%3A%22%22%2C%22bank_ac%22%3A%22012102102%22%2C%22bank_name%22%3A%22bfbdbfsb%22%2C%22routing_no%22%3A%227895464%22%2C%22bank_address%22%3A%22iykeidukpaye%40yahoo.com%22%2C%22bank_country%22%3A%228%22%2C%22bank_ac_type%22%3A%22current%22%2C%22bank_ac_name%22%3A%22IykeIdukpaye%22%2C%22bank_ac_address1%22%3A%22Test%20Test%20%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Teest%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%22%2C%22bank_ac_address2%22%3A%22Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%22%2C%22dr_cr_card%22%3A%22Mc%22%2C%22purpose_code%22%3A%22CONSULTING%22%2C%22confirmation_code%22%3A%22%22%2C%22dispatcher%22%3A%221%22%2C%22dispatch_plan%22%3A%225%22%2C%22dispatcher_id%22%3A%22TDP10LDI%22%2C%22dispatcher_location%22%3A%22%5B%5C%22Local%5C%22%2C%5C%22Domestic%5C%22%2C%5C%22International%5C%22%5D%22%2C%22merchant%22%3A%225%22%2C%22verify%22%3A%220%22%2C%22customer_phone1%22%3A%220%22%2C%22customer_phone2%22%3A%220%22%2C%22verify1%22%3A%220%22%2C%22verify2%22%3A%220%22%2C%22dispatch_status%22%3A%220%22%2C%22dispatch_limit%22%3A%2234800%22%2C%22Ratings%22%3A%220%22%2C%22deviceNotificationToken%22%3Anull%2C%22bankname%22%3A%22ANTARCTICA%22%7D%7D&login=%7B%22username%22%3A%22escw%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22escrndtrust%22%7D&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=voy5xrGfTWNs6nSFAAAr
```

And my url looks like this:

```
ws://52.11.67.123:6060/socket.io/?user=%7B%22user%22%3A%7B%22customer_group_id%22%3A%220%22%2C%22customer_unique_id%22%3A%22271113lq034225%22%2C%22bank_name%22%3A%22bfbdbfsb%22%2C%22dispatch_plan%22%3A%225%22%2C%22verify2%22%3A%220%22%2C%22verify%22%3A%220%22%2C%22verify1%22%3A%220%22%2C%22customer_phone%22%3A%220%22%2C%22date_login%22%3A%222016-10-04%2009%3A22%3A47%22%2C%22password%22%3A%2281dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055%22%2C%22dispatcher%22%3A%221%22%2C%22bank_ac_type%22%3A%22current%22%2C%22dr_cr_card%22%3A%22Mc%22%2C%22routing_no%22%3A%227895464%22%2C%22is_forget_password%22%3A%220%22%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22iykeone%22%2C%22purpose_code%22%3A%22CONSULTING%22%2C%22bank_ac_address1%22%3A%22Test%20Test%20%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Teest%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%22%2C%22date_added%22%3A%222013-11-27%2003%3A42%3A25%22%2C%22phonecode%22%3A%220%22%2C%22dispatcher_location%22%3A%22%5B%5C%22Local%5C%22%2C%5C%22Domestic%5C%22%2C%5C%22International%5C%22%5D%22%2C%22bank_ac_address2%22%3A%22Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%20Test%22%2C%22bank_country%22%3A%228%22%2C%22bank_address%22%3A%22iykeidukpaye%40yahoo.com%22%2C%22phonecode2%22%3A%220%22%2C%22phonecode1%22%3A%220%22%2C%22customer_add%22%3A%22%22%2C%22online_status%22%3A%220%22%2C%22customer_phone1%22%3A%220%22%2C%22customer_phone2%22%3A%220%22%2C%22bankname%22%3A%22ANTARCTICA%22%2C%22merchant%22%3A%225%22%2C%22bank_ac%22%3A%22012102102%22%2C%22status%22%3A%220%22%2C%22Ratings%22%3A%220%22%2C%22confirmation_code%22%3A%22%22%2C%22business_info%22%3A%22%22%2C%22dispatcher_id%22%3A%22TDP10LDI%22%2C%22dispatch_status%22%3A%220%22%2C%22bank_ac_name%22%3A%22IykeIdukpaye%22%2C%22photo%22%3A%22upload%5C%2F1504896445753.png%22%2C%22ip%22%3A%22%22%2C%22address%22%3A%2230%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22iykeidukpaye%40gmail.com%22%2C%22is_company%22%3A%221%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22Idukpaye%22%2C%22dispatch_limit%22%3A%2234800%22%2C%22business_type%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22customer_id%22%3A%2210%22%7D%7D&login=%7B%22username%22%20%3A%20%22esw%22%2C%22password%22%20%3A%20%22esrowtrust%22%7D&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=voy5xrGfTWNs6nSFAAAr
```

I don't understand why it is not getting connect.
The error is:

Error : Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 Bad Request'

What should I do to connect to socket with query parameters?
Please help. Thank you..

Comment: What changes did you make to the url?

Comment: I have added socket.io/ and query parameters also EIO,transport ,sid as hard coded as clients url to check whether I can connect to the socket. @jwils

Comment: Maybe try just making 1 small change to the url at a time (install of all at once) to try and figure out if one of those changes is causing the problem.

Comment: I tried every change, by providing only login object, by not providing socket.io, by providing all parameters, if I am missing any of these parameters I get the error Error : unexpected end of stream on Connection{52.11.67.123:6060, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=/52.11.67.123:6060 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}, but after providing also Iam not able to connect. Can you help with this please I am stucked up.